# Action after ActivateItem in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a question. I have button where i launch `ActivateItem`:

```
    public void LoadTaskManagerPage()
    {
        this.ActivateItem(new TaskManagerViewModel(this.LoggedUser, this.repository));

        if (this.LoggedUser.GetUserTask() != null)
        {
            this.IsActiveTaskButtonVisible = Visibility.Visible;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.IsActiveTaskButtonVisible);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to `hang` an app and go to `if` statement only, if `ActivateItem` ends?

How to wait for end of `ActivateItem` in Caliburn.Micro?

**EDIT:**

Trying something like:

```
    public void LoadTaskManagerPage()
    {
        var taskManagerTask = Task.Run(() => this.ActivateItem(new TaskManagerViewModel(this.LoggedUser, this.repository)));
        taskManagerTask.Wait();

        if (!this.LoggedUser.GetUserTask().IsTaskTakenByUser())
        {
            this.IsActiveTaskButtonVisible = Visibility.Visible;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.IsActiveTaskButtonVisible);
        }
    }
```

With Tasks, but when i click on `LoadTaskManagerPage()` it wont show any window, application hangs forever

**EDIT2**

Based on my [issue](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/607) on github, i upgraded Caliburn to `alpha 4.0`:

```
public void LoadTaskManagerPage()
    {
        this.ActivateItemAsync(new TaskManagerViewModel(this.LoggedUser, this.repository));

        if (!this.LoggedUser.GetUserTask().IsTaskTakenByUser())
        {
            //logic
        }
    }
```

i changed `ActiveItem()` to `ActiveItemAsync()` but still, it hit `if` statement before active item will close. using `async/await` do the same

**EDIT3**

When i make `async/await` it still works the same, look at my view on the right. Its clicked, `User Control` not appear. In the same time (even when my `User Control` not show up) im hitting `if` statement too early. I want to hit it on `User Control` close.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you wanted to use async and await here. Hope this helps you https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/async-and-await-in-c-sharp/

Comment: You can look on my edit please

Comment: You need to await `ActivateItemAsync`.  But what do you mean by "before active item will close"? What happens when you call `ActivateItemAsync` and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @mm8 Im looking solution for my problem. I launch `ActivateItemAsync()` and i want to wait for end of it, and THEN i want to go to `if()` statement. As you can see in **EDIT2**, i tried `await/async` and i go to `If` statement in the same time, as i click `LoadTaskmanagerPage` button, that activates `User Control` `TaskmanagerViewModel`

Comment: @michasaucer: You don't await the method in EDIT2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should await the `ActivateItemAsync` method. This means that your `LoadTaskManagerPage()` should return a `Task` and you should `await` this one as well:

```
public async Task LoadTaskManagerPageAsynnc()
{
    await this.ActivateItemAsync(new TaskManagerViewModel(this.LoggedUser, this.repository));

    if (!this.LoggedUser.GetUserTask().IsTaskTakenByUser())
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```

Comment: As i said in **Edit2**, it not work. Look into my **Edit3**

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I want to wait for window closed (that is mapped to `TaskManagerViewModel`) and then, go to if statement that i mentioned in my function in original post. Im looking for solution for it

Comment: Why would ActivateItemAsync close a window...?

Comment: It wouldnt, i want to catch that screen was closed in `ActivateItemAsync`, then go to `if`

Comment: `ActivateItemAsync` activates an item. It doesn't "catches a screen that was closed".